# Eliminar Array de array según elemento

Tags: array, eliminar, polyfill

Tengo este array

```
var data = [['prueba123', '0021_pruebas', 'Entrada', '12', '12', '144', 'PRUEBA147', '', '30368', '35', 0, -1, 0]
,['aaaaa', 'aaaaaaa', 'Entrada', '12', '12', '144', 'PRUEBA147', '', '30365', '35', 0, -1, 0]
,['sdafsda', 'áéíóú', 'Entrada', '12', '10000', '120000', 'PRUEBA147', '', '30303', '35', 0, -1, 0]]
```

y necesito eliminar uno de ellos según uno de sus valores.

Por ejemplo eliminar el array que contenga '30303'

Esto me funciona:
data = data.filter(subarr => subarr.includes('30303'))

Pero includes no funciona en Internet Explorer y no entiendo como aplicar el polyfill

Ojalá puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar como condición en el filtro si el valor es encontrado en alguna posición del array con indexOf. El método indexOf tiene soporte para Internet Explorer.

Te quedaría asi:

```js
var data = [['prueba123', '0021_pruebas', 'Entrada', '12', '12', '144', 'PRUEBA147', '', '30368', '35', 0, -1, 0]
,['aaaaa', 'aaaaaaa', 'Entrada', '12', '12', '144', 'PRUEBA147', '', '30365', '35', 0, -1, 0]
,['sdafsda', 'áéíóú', 'Entrada', '12', '10000', '120000', 'PRUEBA147', '', '30303', '35', 0, -1, 0]];

let arr = data.filter(subarr => subarr.indexOf('30303') < 0);

console.log(data);
console.log(arr);
```

Siendo la condición, que filtre el array que no lo contiene, que es lo que pides, filter devolverá los valores donde indexOf sea negativo (no encontrado) según el valor dado